# Authors and licenses of wallpaper images

Tags: release-loki, desktop, wallpaper

[image: Desktop]

elementary OS has some beautiful wallpapers, which I imagine are open source, but I was surprised to find no details on their authorship in the Desktop pane of Settings. Where can I find information on the authors and their licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to **`/usr/share/backgrounds`** (or [here](https://github.com/elementary/wallpapers)) to find the name of the wallpaper image file
2. Find the corresponding license at https://github.com/elementary/wallpapers/blob/master/debian/copyright

(Some of the images do not have have free licenses.)

Answer (score 0):

As of (at least) elementary OS 5 Juno and later, artist information is shown on hover in the Desktop settings. More information about each wallpaper can also be found in [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/elementary/wallpapers/blob/deb-packaging/debian/copyright).

[image: Screenshot of Wallpapers]